# PHP quotes with a like query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, quotes

I have gotten myself into a tangled mess with quotes.

I am trying to do a like query that looks something like this

```
$myQuery = 'SELECT col1 , col2 from my_table WHERE col_value LIKE '%$my_string_variable%';
```

But this query would obviously give an error.  What is the right syntax for this?  I tried messing with double-quotes, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try to put a blink tag around your query?!?!?!? Crazy man

Comment: @Byron Blinking SQL query... why didn't I think of that?

Comment: I am so spaced out at the moment, I am not sure what I did wrong...put a blink tag around something......what...I didn't do it right? :)

Comment: @Genadinik `<blink>`'s only valid child is `<marquee>`.

Comment: uh, not sure exactly what you're trying to do here... do you mean you want character escape? \ [backslash] ?? Also, you can't have the variable evaluate without either: double quotes "foo $myVar bar" or concatenation- 'foo '.$myVar.' bar'

Comment: To whom should I give correct answer to? There are like 2 correct answers :)

Comment: But the earliest was Byron.  Hmmmm...what do I do?  Guys, I am just gona pick randomly - I appreciate all your efforts.

Comment: Richards is the better answer. Good choice.

Comment: @Genadinik - you can hover over the "answered X minutes ago" time to see the real time. Byron was just 8 seconds late from the first post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine double and single quotes.

```
$myQuery = "SELECT col1 , col2
            FROM my_table
            WHERE col_value LIKE '%$my_string_variable%'";
```

Although I prefer to protect my code against SQL Injection..

```
$myQuery = "SELECT col1 , col2
            FROM my_table
            WHERE col_value LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($my_string_variable) . "%'";
```

Answer (score 4):

Surround the whole thing in double quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT col1 , col2 from my_table WHERE col_value LIKE '%$my_string_variable%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes inside a single quote delimited string. Try using double quotes to quote your string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myQuery = "SELECT col1 , col2 from my_table WHERE col_value LIKE '%$my_string_variable%'";
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You use a single quote as the start of your string and again single quotes "inside" it. You could change it to the following:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT col1 , col2 from my_table WHERE col_value LIKE '%$my_string_variable%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one just in case you don't wanna break the pattern of your query.

```
$myQuery = 'SELECT col1 , col2 from my_table WHERE col_value LIKE "%' .$my_string_variable . '%"';
```

When you apply single quote don't include the php variable inside it as this single quote treats everything inside it as value not variable.